# Disabled checkbox with Capybara

Tags: rspec, capybara

How can I verify with Capybara that a checkbox is disabled?

I have tried few options but nothing seems to work. Last attempt was

```
expect(page).to have_field("input[type='checkbox'][value='agreement']", disabled: true)
```

As always, Thanks.

Comment: expect(page).to have_field("input[type='checkbox'][value='agreement']", checked: false)   -   Been a long time since I used Capybara, but I think "checked" was the part you want

Comment: Or maybe expect(page.find("input[type='checkbox'][value='agreement']")).not_to be_checked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_field%3F-instance_method - the `have_field` matcher **takes label, name or id of a field to check for**, it does not take a CSS selector. So you either need to pass the name, id or associated label text of the expected element to the matcher. Doing that with everything else you're checking in your selector would be something like.

```
expect(page).to have_field('id_of_checkbox', type: 'checkbox', with: 'agreement', disabled: true)
```

If you're using a recent Capybara you can also skip the id/name/label text if the other options would restrict to a unique element.

```
expect(page).to have_field(type: 'checkbox', with: 'agreement', disabled: true)
```

If you want to do this with a CSS selector instead, then you could use the `:disabled` CSS3 pseudo selector with the `have_css` matcher

```
expect(page).to have_css("input[type='checkbox'][value='agreement']:disabled")
```

Comment: Thanks, `expect(page).to have_field(type: 'checkbox', with: 'agreement', disabled: true)` with a small adjustment works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for a similar solution when checking for disabled state for a hidden checkbox, you can use:

```
expect(page).to have_field('id_of_element', type: 'checkbox', disabled: false, visible: :hidden)
```

`visible: :hidden` will tell capybara to also look for fields that are not visible